# where is this kind of syntax used in javascript (function(){}())

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Person = function() {
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Person.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };
    console.log("called")
    return Person;
}();
var p = new Person('John');
console.log('Person 1 name: ' + p.getName());
```

Here, Person is assigned something as `(function(){}())` syntax, what is this syntax about and what is it doing, Please someone explain this...
I saw this code somewhere and I am not able to understand where the parenthesis after function syntax (function(){}**()**) came from and what are they doing.

**On removing the second set of parenthesis it stops behaving as a constructor, Why so**

Comment: possible a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Comment: This is a self-invoking function. You can find hundreds of articles about it on google.

Comment: As some comments and answers in the dupe state, the standard name for this is "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" (or IIFE); it even has its own tag: [tag:iife]

Answer (score 1):

The first `()` is declaring it as a function - this is where parameters passed in would go if there were any.

`{}` is where the logic is declared.

The second `()` calls the function immediately after it is defined, as opposed to it being called from somewhere else.

Comment: Ok now I got it, Can you answer another query i.e.: When I remove the second `()` parenthesis then it no more works as a constructor, why so...

Comment: @AyushAgrawal First `()` is `definition`, Second `()` is `initialisation`. The function has to be initialised/executed for the inner logic to work.

Comment: @AyushAgrawal It will work fine without the second parentheses if you call it as `Person()`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gq3mrwx/) for a demo.

Comment: `var Person = function() {`
`    function Person(name) {`
 `       this.name = name;`
    `}`

    `Person.prototype.getName = function() {`
`        return this.name;`
 `   };`
    `console.log("called")`
`    return Person;`
`}();`
`var p = new Person('John');`
`console.log('Person 1 name: ' + p.getName());`

@JamesWhiteley In this code if i remove the second () it no more works as a constructor